# Ошибка Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open при загрузке файла с использованием multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

html form:

```js
form(
    action="/profile/"+ user._id +"/user-img" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
)
    input(type="file" name="img" required)
    input(type="submit" value="Load")
```

middleware file:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'upload');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
    }   
});

const allowedTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'];

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

module.exports = multer({
    storage, fileFilter
})
```

route:

```js
router.post('/:id/user-img', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const userFind = await User.findById(req.params.id);

        await User.updateOne({
            email: userFind.email
        },{$set: {
            img: req.file.path
        }})

        res.redirect('/profile/'+userFind._id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
})
```

server:

```js
app.use(fileMiddleware.single('img'));
```

> Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open...`

Хотя папка upload у меня есть, но туда ничего не загружается, что не так?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48418680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> filename(req, file, cb) {
>   cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
> }
> ```

*Двоеточия ":" не допускаются в именах файлов в операционной системе Windows.*

Так что, нужно после `new Date().toISOString()` добавить вызов `replace()`, в котором заменить ":" любым допустимым символом.

Например:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653921/6571020) участника [Miles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9324780/miles) на вопрос [ENOENT: no such file or directory .?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48418680)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653921